# PHP 7.4 on raspbian

Tags: raspbian, php

I'm trying for about 4 hours to install PHP 7.4 on my Raspberry Pi Zero W.

I tried different tutorials, but I endup crashing my raspbian completly or just the installed php. With crashing I mean, I get the following message: `Illegal instruction`.

I also tried to install diffrent raspbians, but nothing worked till now.

Is it even possible to use PHP 7.4 on a raspberry pi?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104330/discussion-on-question-by-mr-tr33-php-7-4-on-raspbian).

Answer (score 20):

### First method:

You can install it manually by:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.4/php7.4_7.4.1-1_all.deb
```

And then:

```
dpkg -i php7.4_7.4.1-1_all.deb
```

It gives you a lot of dependencies which you must install before this package. It's the hardest method. **Look at the second method which is much easier.**

---

### Second method:

Ensure your system is updated:

```
sudo apt update
```

Download and store the PPA repository in a file but first, download the GPG key:

```
sudo apt -y install lsb-release apt-transport-https ca-certificates

sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
```

Then add the repository:

```
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
```

The last step is to install PHP 7.4 on your Raspbian Buster. Before installation, update the system package list on added repositories:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then install PHP 7.4:

```
sudo apt -y install php7.4
```

I just tested it and worked. I got the exact version by `php -v`:

```
PHP 7.4.2 (cli) (built: Feb  2 2020 07:53:49) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.2, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104329/discussion-on-answer-by-m-rostami-php-7-4-on-raspbian).

Comment: resulted in Segmentation fault, can't autoremove it anymore :/

Comment: @clockw0rk Which method you've followed?

Comment: The second one. Seems like there has changed a lot with php, wordpress and so on this year. switched to a different bloggin software now, since i could not even get nginx to install properly on raspian. they really should update the arm-package list

Comment: You get my upvote. Followed method 2 in feb 2021 and got the expected results on raspberry os buster. It is always nice to see a good answer which explains each step.

Comment: Second method is perfect as of 13 April 2021, Linux raspberrypi 4.19.66-v7.
PHP 7.4.16 (cli) (built: Mar  5 2021 08:37:59) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.16, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Comment: At a glance, that second method is going to require specific things of the shell you're using. If you're not familiar with how to translate it, bash works for certain. Edit: I take that back, it looks like the variable expansion works in most/all shells.

Comment: Works with Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit lite in October 2021!

Comment: Worked in April 2022 with Raspberry Pi 32-bit OS running on Pi 4. I also used some extra instructions from this post (for Apache-specific stuff): https://dev.to/samtarling/upgrading-apache-from-php-7-3-to-php-7-4-3a3h