# Raspberry PI Zero PHP7.4 Buster

Tags: pi-zero-w, raspbian-buster

I have been trying to install the php7.4 on the Raspberry Pi Zero but it seems the device cannot run that version, as I keep getting illegal instruction error after installing the packages.
Guides I followed: https://janw.me/2019/installing-php7-4-rapsberry-pi/ and other similar guides with the same instructions.
This similar question does not seem to have been able to do it: [PHP 7.4 on raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108149/php-7-4-on-raspbian)
I am installing the armhf version from the repository before anyone asks.
Has anyone been able to run the php7.4 on  Rpi Zero W specifically?
Can anyone confirm?
Thank you

Comment: From my perspective you have downloaded and run a package of unknown provenance from a site with unknown provenance.  This is how security breaches happen.

Comment: If you are desperate (for whatever reason) to install php7.4 on ARM6 you will need to compile from source - you will not find an existing deb. You may also have to compile dependencies.